# Xcode 6.4 iOS device/Simulator and Scheme option disappear in OS X El capitan

Tags: ios-simulator, osx-elcapitan, xcode6.4

I've update Mac from *OS X Yosemite 10.10.4* to *OS X El Capitan 10.11.1* recently. After OS update the `iOS device/Simulator list and Scheme option` that appears right next to build/run option *disappeared* completely. I'm using Xcode 6.4.

[image: Screenshot for error 1]

I've found something new feature `>>` button next to *Utilities* tab on top-right corner after update to OS X El Capitan shown in screenshot. After clicking `>>` button `Scheme` button appears but is disabled.

[image: Screenshot for error 2]

Is this any kind of big or feature? Any fix/workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got fix for using Xcode 6.x on OS X El Capitan.

[image: Screenshot 1]

**For Scheme :**

You can select scheme using `Product menu -> Scheme -> Select Scheme`

You can also *edit, manage or add scheme* using above steps.

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

[image: Screenshot 4]

**For Destination :**

You can select destination using `Product menu -> Destination -> Select destination` from drop-down list.

[image: Screenshot 5]

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen as well.  The issue seems to be that the field will disappear if the window isn't wide enough.  If you resize the window to make it wider, the run destinations field should appear.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is to *`use Xcode 7 or above`*. I've *installed Xcode 7.1 and found Scheme/Simulator list available*. Refer screenshot.

It seems that Xcode 6 or below doesn't support OS X El Capitan.

[image: Screenshot for solution]